# Git workflow two: Split 1 PR split into 2 PRs

Tags: git

I encounter a situation, and I want to know what is the professional way to solve it. The scenario is like this: (PR = Pull Request)

1. I have one PR with about 2000+ lines of code.
2. For the ease of reviewing, I have to split it into two PRs: 1300+ lines PR called `A`, and 700+ lines called `B`.

Now here are the problems I have observed:

1. After the review of `A`, there is a high chance that I will need to change `A`. Since `B` is dependent on `A`, there will be many conflicts with `A` after `A` is refactored and merged into the `master` branch.
2. I will need to make progress on `B` when `A` is being reviewed, but during the development of `B` I will probably need to go back refactoring `A`.

So what's the best practice in this situtation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it comes to the the best practices.. That would be not to have such large commits in the first place :) If you're asking for the easiest way to resolve this problem:

1. Instead of creating `A` and `B` PRs - create just `A`. It should be as small as possible so that it gets reviewed as quickly as possible.
2. The rest of the changes - either stash them, or commit them into separate temporary branch. *Do not work on them in parallel*. Your goal is to get your 1st PR get pushed into trunk as fast as possible.
3. Finally push it into the trunk. Do whatever is possible to expedite the review.
4. After it's in the trunk, merge it with your stashed changes. Since `A` was (hopefully) small - it shouldn't result into too many conflicts.
5. Goto #1 and create a PR for the next portion.

This whole process may result in several commits. Better have many small commits than few larger ones.

Answer (score 1):

**In general I recommend avoiding this scenario completely whenever possible.** (This is basically what Stanislav's answer recommends, and I agree.) Sometimes that means just waiting and working on something else until the PR for `A` is completed. There's almost always something else you could be working on that does not depend on `A`.

**But if it's just not practical to wait:**

As soon as the new and improved A' is merged into `master`, do the following to your `B` branch:

1. Get to a clean state by stashing, undoing, or committing any pending changes.
2. `git checkout B # if not already`
3. `git fetch # this should be obvious but you'd be surprised how often it's forgotten`
4. `git rebase --onto origin/master A B # resolve any conflicts you have`

**Why this works:**

The "fancy" rebase with the `--onto` argument enables you to "rebuild" or "rewrite" your branch as if you had branched off of `master` in the first place. It is basically the same thing as:

```
git checkout B
git reset --hard origin/master
git cherry-pick A..B # cherry pick this range of commits
```

So, make `B` look just like `origin/master`.
Now replay each of your commits on `B` that was not on your local copy of `A`. Note that if you don't have a local copy of `A`, you don't want to use `origin/A` here, because it has likely been changed since you created your `B` branch. In that case you can substitute the commit-IDs instead of the branch names in both the `rebase` and `cherry-pick` commands. Replace `A` with the *parent* of the first commit you want to keep, and replace `B` with the last commit you want to keep. One caveat here, if you use `rebase --onto` with commit IDs you may end up in detached mode. In that case you can get back to `B` by doing `git switch -C B` which will force you back into the B branch on your current commit.

Note that if you get a bunch of conflicts with the rebase and are a little uncomfortable about it, you may wish to abort the rebase, and then create a new branch and cherry pick instead. That makes it a little easier to look at your old branch and new one for compares. If you go that route then simply rename the new temporary branch to `B` when you're done, or just PR the new branch into `master` instead of `B`.